# Filtering content in Text::Xslate

Tags: perl, text-xslate

In [Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mason/lib/Mason/Manual/Syntax.pod#%3C%25filter-name-params%3E) i could define a filter:

```
<%filter Div($class)>
        <div class="<% $class %>">
                <% $yield->() %>
        </div>
</%filter>
```

And later i could use it

```
% $.Div("row") {{
   1 The "$yield->()" method returns everything from here (free text)
%       $.Div("col") {{
                2 even could have another nested filter, etc...
%       }}
% }}
```

with result

```
<div class="row">
    1 The "$yield->()" method returns everything from here (free text)
   <div class="col">
            2 even could have another nested filter, etc...   
   </div>
</div>
```

E.g. the `$yield->()` method returns everything what is inside of the enclosed filter.

Want achieve same functionality using [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate::Syntax::Kolon), but don't know how.

The closest thing what I found ,are the [macro blocks](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate::Syntax::Kolon#Macro-blocks) where i could write:

```
: macro div -> ($cls,$str) {
<div class="<: $cls :>">
        <: $str :>
</div>
: }
```

and use it as

```
: div("row",
:       div("col",
:               "my string"
:       )
: )
```

but the `my string` must be quoted and `:` marked, so it is impossible to use  any free html text. E.g. the following dies.

```
: div("row",

some free text here

:       div("col",
               nested
               here
:       )
: )
```

After the long introduction, the question is simple:

Exists in the `Text::Xslate` something as the Mason's `$yield->()` call, which returns the content of the enclosed filter call? (or if not exists, how i could mimic it?)